# Specify Content-Length while serving a file from the database

Tags: java, tomcat, servlets

In a servlet, I want to read an EML from my database and serving it to the client with a "download file" UI. When I specify the `Content-Length` header, the download takes minutes to start. When I don't, everything works well, but I do want to set that header :) What am I missing?

```
// part is javax.mail.Part
response.setHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment" + filename);
response.setContentType(mime);
response.setContentLength(part.getSize()); // This line causes the problem
IOUtils.copy(part.getInputStream(), out);
```

Comment: Why do you want to set the Content-Length header? It is not necessary for HTTP/1.1 clients

Comment: It's just a question :) moreover, I don't know if that field is really optional [RFC2616](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec14.html#sec14.13)

Comment: @Mark: It's not necessary, but it would be nice for users so they can see how much of the download has finished and how much is remaining. If there is no Content-Length header, the browser doesn't get the info and can't display it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just a guess - maybe the file has to be fetched from DB to get its size ? Save the **size to separate column** and serve the value from there. Also working with the file-in-DB through **java.sql.Blob** should work.

Unfortunately in your sample there is no info where you take the part object from.

Comment: I have the whole EML stored in the DB. At runtime I reconstruct a MimeMessage and write the requested Part to servlet response

Comment: How large is the part?  Is it something that you would expect to take minutes to retrieve in its entirety?

Comment: The parts are typically few bytes, except some pdf accounting for 3-400KB. Without the Content-Length, the download finishes in no time (since I'm testing on localhost), so the issue seems to be with that value. From Part javadoc, getSize() is designed to return an estimate, not an exact size, so it seems more a browser failure to me, but it affects all browsers...

Comment: Part.getSize() returns a rough estimate. In that case, the estimate was larger than the real size and this caused the browser to wait the extra time before realizing that there were really nothing more to be transmitted